# What would be suitable "Done", "Now", Next" icons?

Tags: icon

For a report I am designing, I want to include "Done", "Now", "Next" icons to show tasks completed, tasks being worked on and tasks next on list.

Is there any convention for this, or does anyone have any good ideas?

Comment: Are there very obvious choices you have considered yourself? If so, why don't you like them?

Comment: Obvious ones I have come up with are Check for done, Hourglass for working on and stuck for an "up next" option.

Comment: check on [ux.se]

Comment: The ellipsis (…) typographic symbol could work for "up next."

Comment: @stan - good shout, didn't think of that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Download [Font Awesome](http://fontawesome.io/) and try a combination of these

- http://fontawesome.io/icon/check-circle/
- http://fontawesome.io/icon/pencil-square/
- http://fontawesome.io/icon/arrow-circle-right/

This is just an example but they do have an extensive [set](http://fontawesome.io/icons/) and you can try different things.